# javax.persistence.Entity generating NullPoint exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Hibernate for ORM in play framework 2.0.4. I have a model class called video that is annotated using JPA. However when I run the application I get the following error

```
   [NullPointerException: null] In C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\projectname\app\models\Video.java at line 4.

 1package models;

2

3 import java.util.Date;
4 import javax.persistence.Entity;
5 import javax.persistence.Id;
6
7@Entity
8public class Video {
```

I have just started learning play and don't have a clue whats causing this problem and how to fix it.
Stack trace
       ! @6d9h9310f - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

```
  play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[NullPo
  interException: null]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [
  play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [
 play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.
 4]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.
  2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.j
   ar:2.0.2]
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at models.Video._ebean_get_video_name(Video.java:4) ~[classes/:na]
    at models.Video.getVideoName(Video.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:15) ~[classes/:2.0.4]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(rout
 es_routing.scala:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(rout
  es_routing.scala:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$5$$anon$1.invocation(Router.sca
```

I realize that then I just call the primary key for the Video Entity I have no problem but when I try to get anyother attribute this happen. I also realize that there is a new column generated in my database called _ebean_intercept which all of its rows are null can this be causing the problem.

Comment: any other logs? obviously line 4 can't cause that

Comment: could you provide Video class's code?